# nautilus unable to see other computers on network

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, share

i have 3 computers in the LAN, 1 server (ubuntu 11.10 server), 2 desktop-pcs (1 windows 7, 1 ubuntu 11.10 desktop)... i shared some folders from the server, the windows and the ubuntu pc, but i can't see them. neither on windows, nor on the ubuntu desktop, however, i can access them if i enter the computername (or ip, both works).

when a friend comes with his windows-laptop and connects to the lan, he can see the shared folders of the windows machine and i can see his shared folders, but we both can't see one of the ubuntu-computers and the ubuntu desktop can't see any share at all...

is there a way to tell ubuntu, respectively nautilus that it bcasts the network and finds the shares?

i have alrdy installed winbind, wins, samba and configured samba to use wins and added wins to /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get ip addresses of the computers you need to access
2. In Nautilus menu click go>location
3. Type in smb://(ip address)
4. A log in prompt SHOULD appear if it can see it on the network.